# Debugging with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to break and look at the `$scope` variable while Angular is evaluating an `ng-change` event?

I have the following as part of the custom footerCellTemplate I'm using with [UI-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/105_footer):

`<select class="form-control" ng-model="col.colDef.stat" ng-options="stat as stat for stat in col.getRenderContainer().grid.stats" ng-change="col.getRenderContainer().grid.update_stat()"></select>`

`ng-options` works fine for the element and I can see the expected options, but `ng-change` does not work even if `update_stat()` has just an `alert`.

`update_stat()` works fine if I run it from the console.
No relevant console errors to report.

How can I check `$scope` for the element while `ng-change` is executing?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xD1bRqO2v4C2iFlPUbxt?p=preview) for anyone who would like to dig deeper.

Comment: Your problem is because you use plain bootrstrap popove, while you need to use AngularUI one. Otherwise events never trigger digest.

Comment: I'll try with AngularUI popover and see if that works.

Comment: Apparently AngularUI popover doesn't allow html inside the popover.